# Need help writing a table in latex

Tags: tables

I am trying to create the below table for a document class called- article. But despite of several attempts one or the other error keeps coming up where the points have an extra space or the heading is off. Can someone please help me out with the code snippet for this table?

[image: png]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: Are you getting a compilation error, or the output doesn't match what you want?  It looks like you're creating a resume; are you working from a template?  Could you cut that template down to just the code that led to the extra space as well as the code where the heading is off?

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for replying. I tried copying some codes from stackexchange to try and modify them to create this table. But the thing is that most of them don't agree with the template/style that I am already using to create the resume, and hence none of them works perfectly in my document due to conflict in packages or whatnot. The original latex code I am using for writing the resume is not my original, I borrowed it from a friend earlier so I don't know how to modify it to suit the tables I copy from stackexchange. Hence I am not able to get the tables working

Comment: @Daffodils, if you are filling in some template, stay with that one (and any instructions it carries). Doesn't matter if you think it looks ugly, whoever gave the template has their workflow arranged around it. If you are making up your own, search for templates, see which ones you like/are easy to work with (the result is important, make it nice; chances are you'll  use it several times with updates/modifications).